# getDouble function in C

Tags: c

I have created a custom function to prompt the user with whatever you want and they need to input a double. The problem is, if I were to enter a number like 1.22 it would print '1' so it doesn't print anything behind the decimal, no rounding

```
int main(void) {
double f = getDouble("Enter a double: ");
printf("%d\n", f);
```

}

```
double getDouble(char* y){
double x;
printf("%s", y);
scanf("%d", &x);
return x;
```

}

Comment: `printf/scanf` have different format specifiers for different types.

Comment: Please enable more warnings in your compiler. You should get some warning about wrong parameter type for `"%d"`

Comment: `%d` stands for integer decimal, not double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are using `printf("%d\n", var);` to print a `double` and you are also using `scanf("%d", &x);` to get a double. You should use `"%lf"` instead as the format specifier of in both `printf` in `scanf`. Your code obviously doesn't work because `scanf` is looking for an integer input and `printf` is trying to print and integer instead of a double.

```
int main(void) {
double f = getDouble("Enter a double: ");
printf("%lf\n", f);

}

double getDouble(char* y){
double x;
printf("%s", y);
scanf("%lf", &x);
return x;

}
```

This should work. You can find format specifiers for every basic type: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Main_types

Use the correct format specifier for the correct type otherwise, the function will try to do things assuming the wrong datatype which will lead to problems.

Comment: Thank you, I actually tried searched this up and found that you should use "lf" but I thought the "l" was the number one(1) and it was doing weird things. I even had trouble writing this because the "I" in "I'm" is very similar looking to the "l" in "hello".

Answer (score 0):

For reading double you need to use "%lf", "%d" is for integer.

```
double getDouble(const char* y) {
    double x;
    printf("%s", y);
    scanf_s("%lf", &x);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    double f = getDouble("Enter a double: ");
    printf("%lf\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In scanf/printf use %lf instead of %d

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

double getDouble(char *y) {
  double x;
  printf("%s", y);
  scanf("%lf", &x);
  return x;
}

int main(void) {
  double f = getDouble("Enter a double: ");
  printf("%lf\n", f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, you are simply using the wrong specifier in `scanf`. They can be confusing without practice.

[Here's a reference.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/format-specifiers-in-c)